# Rails many-to-many association with single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, single-table-inheritance

This problem involves a rails ActiveRecord many-to-many association and a case of single-table-inheritance. I am struggling to get the association `Patient` -> `Membership` to work. All other associations work as expected.

Note that `Member` (below) contains foreign key fields for `membership_id` and `patient_id`.

So far I have experimented with various combinations of options for the associations but haven't managed to find the correct setup to make the association work

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
end

class Membership < LineItem
  has_many :members, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :line_item_id, inverse_of: :membership
  has_many :patients, through: :members
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :membership, foreign_key: :line_item_id, inverse_of: :members
  belongs_to :patient, optional: true
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  has_many :memberships, through: :members
end
```

Let `patient_1` be an instance of `Patient`.
Let `membership_1` be an instance of `Membership`.
Let them be associated through `member_1`, an instance of `Member`.

I would expect `patient_1.memberships` to return `membership_1` (contained within ActiveRecord Relation).

Instead I am getting the following error:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column line_items.member_id does not exist`

Comment: In my own limited experience with single table inheritance, the relationships still need to be defined on the model being inheited from. It's the methods you define, ie scope, enums, instance method that you can change on each model. But the relationships need to be on the model that has a table in the db. 
I may be wrong but that's what I had to do when I started playing with single table inheritance

Comment: I will give this a try. Would love to hear any advice others might have.

Comment: Same ^, my experience is literally from one attempt. I just threw stuff at the wall and saw what stuck while tracing the errors, lol

Comment: I've solved it. There was a method contained within a concern with the same name as the association. That method was getting called. Oops!

So it turns out you can define the associations on the child model after all

Comment: Oh nice! Congratz! And thanks for letting me know. Will definitely help in refactoring for me in the future :D